# VS Code debugger: failure to find module (utf-8 characters)

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, utf-8

When I try to run a Node.js debugging session from Visual Code, the debugging console returns an error, saying that the bootloader.bundle.js could not be found. However, the bootloader.bundle.js file exists at the expected location, while the debug console specifies the folder incorrectly *by substituting a UTF-8 character (letter č) with the replacement character (�)*. The snippet of the error message can be found below:

> Error: Cannot find module 'c:/Users/xxxx xxxx�/AppData/Local/Programs/
> Microsoft VS Code/resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/bootloader.bundle.js'

Can I somehow fix this in VS Code, perhaps by modifying the launch.json file in some way or some other settings?

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
I temporarily fixed the issue by reinstalling VS Code to another folder without that doesn't include diacritical characters. I'd like to to keep this question open, however, in case somebody knows of a way to fix this sort of problem (e.g. by by modifying some configuration files) that does not require either reinstalling or relying on a [portable version](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable) of the app.

Answer (score 2):

I have just dealt with the same issue. There have been Unicode characters in my folder's path and I got the same error "Cannot find module". Reasons are described in details [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/34399).

To fix it I have gone to File - Preferences - Settings and then entered "usePreview" and then I unchecked the option "Use the new in-preview JavaScript debugger for ..." under the section "Debug > JavaScript: Use Preview" and reloaded VS Code. The issue has gone.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion, I'm sure it will be helpful to other people as well. As for me, I just stuck with the original solution of reinstalling VSCode in a different location, but now I'm having similar problems with MongoDB :( I just wish that developers would put more consideration into the fact that many users come from countries that use special letters and that those letters may consequently appear in directory names as well :)

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work for me. Still getting the below error 
n\nError: Cannot find module '/private/var/folders/7g/***/T/AppTranslocation/****/d/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/ms-vscode.js-debug/src/bootloader.bundle.js'\nRequire stack:\n- internal/preload\n    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)\n

Comment: @AshlinKarkada, did you find any solution for it?

Comment: @DeekshaPandit Unfortunately I did not

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:
https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-js-debug#nightly-extension

---

**Nightly Extension**

The shipped version of VS Code includes the js-debug version at the time of its release, however you may want to install our nightly build to get the latest fixes and features. The nightly build runs at 5PM PST on each day that there are changes (see pipeline). To get the build:

1. Open the extensions view (ctrl+shift+x) and search for @builtin
   @id:ms-vscode.js-debug
2. List item
3. Right click on the JavaScript Debugger extension and Disable it.
4. Search for @id:ms-vscode.js-debug-nightly in the extensions view.
   Install that extension.